# Why is my binding not working for my property?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**EDIT** : solved this by using an IValueConverter which i didn't know existed as  @tym32167 said in the comments. ( I still don't understand why the way i did it wouldn't work tho.)

I want to be able to change the BackGroundColor to green if the value saved in my ViewModel is <= 85 but the way i did it doesn't work.

What am i doing wrong ? Thanks

[Debuger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhbmU.png)

This is what i tried :

**TasksGroupPage.xaml**

```
<Span Text="{Binding TaskDBA}" BackgroundColor="{Binding ResultColor}"/>
```

**Created myself a ResultColor property in my BaseViewModel.cs**

```
private Color resultColor;
public Color ResultColor
{
    get => resultColor;
    set
    {
        resultColor = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

**NewTaskPageViewModel.cs which is where i have my saving command**

```
 async Task SaveNewTask()
        {

            IsBusy = true;
            await Task.Delay(4000);
            IsBusy = false;

            TasksGroup tasksGroup = new TasksGroup();
            Tasks tasks = new Tasks();

            tasksGroup.TasksGroupDescription = TasksGroupDescription;
            tasksGroup.TasksGroupDate = TasksGroupDate;
            tasks.TaskDuration = TaskDuration;
            tasks.TaskDBA = TaskDBA;
            tasks.TaskDescription = TaskDescription;

// this is where i verify the value

            if (tasks.TaskDBA <= 85)
            {
                ResultColor = Color.Green;
            }


            tasksGroup.Taches = new List<Tasks>() { tasks };


            if(ValidateTasksGroup(tasksGroup) && ValidateTasks(tasks))
            {
                await App.Database.SaveTasksGroupAsync(tasksGroup);

                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Save", "La tâche a été enregistrée", "OK");
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
                

                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }


        }
```

Comment: I would go with converter in such case ([example on ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/986736/179763))

Comment: 1. is your setter getting called?  2. is your code running on a non-UI thread?  3. is your NotifyPropertyChange implemented correctly?

Comment: @Jason 1. i added a debug screenshot, it seems to be called.2. i'm not sure what you want me to do there 3. Yyes the NotifyProperty works.

Comment: 2. was a question.  If you are not on the UI thread UI updates will not work.  3. Your use of NotifyPropertyChanged at the bottom of the method makes me question whether or not you're actually using it correctly.

Comment: Everything is working fine to save something, the color is just something that i added, in the screenshot i tested with NotifyPropertyChanged() under ResultColor just to test.

Comment: I implemented a IValueConverter like @tym32167 said and it worked !

Comment: speaking about your initial problem, I will just try to do blind guess that you used `Color` here as property type `public Color ResultColor` , but try to use `Brush` or `SolidColorBrush` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to Created myself a ResultColor property in my BaseViewModel.cs

```
public Color resultColor;
public Color ResultColor
{
    get
    {
        return resultColor;
    }

    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref resultColor, value);
    }
```

}